# How to get the DOM element of an `observer` wrapped component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, mobx

I have defined my JSX components like this:

```js
const ComponentA = observer(({state}) => {return <div></div>})
```

I am using `observer` from mobx:
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html

I need to see what the rendered height is of the div by using the browser API for the DOM node. It will differ based on the contents it contains.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you're trying to get at. Perhaps this will help?

```
const divRef = useRef();

useEffect(() => {
  console.log(divRef.current.clientHeight);
}, []);

return <div ref={divRef}></div>
```

Comment: This works for the first render, but after subsequent renders which change the div height `useEffect` is not longer called.

Comment: You can add dependency in useEffect. useEffect(() => {some code}, [some dependency]), and useEffect will run after changed dependency. Or you can remove dependency array from useEffect, and it will be run each render. useEffect(() => {some code})

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to use `ResizeObserver` inside the `useEffect` along with `useEffect(f1, [divRef])`

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver